# When is $e^f$ convex for non-convex $f$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, convex-analysis

Assuming that $f(x)\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ is non-convex, when is $e^{f(t)}$ convex? Clearly the function $\exp:\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty)$ preserves convexity under composition:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} e^{f(t)}=e^f\left(f'^2+f''\right)\ge 0$$
whenever $f''\ge 0$. But when does it create convexity when it previously did not exist? The question is equivalent to $f$ satisfying the differential inequality
$$0>f''\ge-(f')^2.$$
Let $f'(t)=v(t)$. Then the inequality reads
$$0>v'\ge-v^2.$$

Comment: 'But when does it create it when it previously did not exist?' - you might wanna clarify this part?

Answer (score 2):

By the [Bihari-LaSall inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bihari%E2%80%93LaSalle_inequality), if $v$ satisfies the differential inequality
$$v'\ge-v^2,\quad v(0)=v_0=f'(0)$$
then we have that
$$v(t)\ge \frac{v_0}{1+v_0t}.$$
Thus, integrating, we find that
$$f(t)\ge f(0)+\log(1+v_0t).$$
Thus, the most relaxed sufficient conditions for the convexity of $e^{f(t)}$ are that $f \in C^2$ and $f(t)\ge f(0)+\log\left[1+tf'(0)\right]$. for all $t$. As a relatively obvious example, we can take $f(t)=\log(1+t)$ so that $f''(t)<0$ for all $t$, but $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}e^f= \frac{d^2}{dt^2} (1+t)\ge 0.$

An example that is less trivial is taking, for any $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, $f(0)=1/\varepsilon, f'(0)=1$, $f'(t)=(1+t)^{-1+\epsilon}\ge (1+t)^{-1}$ for any $t\ge 0$. Then, integrating, $f(t)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}(1+t)^\varepsilon$. Thus, the function $\exp\left[\frac{1}{\varepsilon}(1+t)^\varepsilon\right]$ is convex for any $t\ge 0$, $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$ even though $f$ is clearly not.